# Javascript, Ajax and form submission/response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm hoping there is a simple solution to this, or else its possible AJAX time!

I WAS using ClickBank. I had a simple button on my page. That sent the form data to a script, I processed the data, and then added a redirect at end of script to jump to the "pay" link. Nice n' easy

But now I'm switching to "Click2Sell" ... and they have a direct href to their site.

Now I COULD use javascript to read the form data, place it into their "cp_" prefix, and create a super long (about 400 chars) query string and send that to their server, then re-read the data at the IPN stage ...

```
?country=UK&area=essex&desc=This is the data entered by the user 'whatever'
```

(but that leads to a little fact that certain parts might need to be escaped(?) such as the spaces and the " ' " or whatever other symbol they enter)

So I devised this method:

```
<javascript>
function send_data(){
document.user.submit();
return true;
}
</javascript>

<div name="noshowdiv"><object name="noshow"></object></div>
<form method="post" target="noshow" name="user">
<input type="text" name="country">
<input type="text" name="area">
<textarea name="desc"></textarea>
</form>
<a href="click2sell.asp"><img src="xxx" onclick="return send_data();"></a>
```

In a nutshell, when the button is clicked, it jumps to the function, and submits the form data to my script, and then returns to the hyperlink to submit the second form via the hyperlink.

Two problems: Firstly, the data returned by my script is opening in a new tab rather than the <div>, (I suspect 'cos the submit option loses track of the sending window) and also, I need to get a response from my script which I can then append to the href link.

For example, if the form records the user's data on line 5 on my server, the script will return "id=5" I would then make the hyperlink "click2sell.asp?cp_id=5"

As I've said, I suspect this is a job for Ajax and a HttpRequest ... which is a whole new area to me. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, it opens a new tab because you have `target="no-show"` on your form.

For the second problem, if you want to use Ajax, I recommend you use jQuery, it will simplify a lot of the code.

But the best option is probably that you completely remove the direct link to click2sell, and just add a submit button to your form. Post the form to your site, which will store whatever info it needs, assigns an ID, and builds the click2sell URL with the ID in one of the parameters, and redirect to it.

Now how you would do that depends on what server-side language you use.

Answer (score 0):

(I think) I have managed to find a work around, which was using the first option to reconstruct the href link. I couldn't iterate through the form as there are values that don't need to be forwarded. First I get the value, load  it into a variable, then use an encode function I discovered online, and then reassign to the form ...

```
var cp_cc=document.getElementById('cc').value;
var cp_cs=document.getElementById('cs').value;  // plus 10 other values
var str='&cp_cc='+encodeURIComponent(cc)+'&cp_cs='+encodeURIComponent(cs)+ // etc
var send_str=document.getElementById('c2s_bn_lnk_36288').href;
document.getElementById('c2s_bn_lnk_36288').href=send_str+str;
```

The "no-show" was a slip up in my typing! Alas, the answer given above wouldn't work as the Click2sell button also includes two calls to external JS files - and they give you no idea what they do, but is something to do with initializing the button, (it passes the "36288" to the script to do ???). And whilst using "Location: ..\n\n" on my server would redirect to their site, it wouldn't action whatever those external files do. (OK, so I didn't give the full facts, but I didn't want to increase the post size with data I felt didn't relate to problem)

** Now got to amend the listening scripts such that rather than set the ID number up front then jump to C2S, it now waits for C2S to send the data back to me and then sets up the database!!